# Can "headfirst" be used in a positive sense?

Tags: idioms, idiomatic-language, connotations

Can I use **head first**, **head-first** or **headfirst** in a positive sense in a sentence like:

> He's not affraid of anything. He delved **head first** into his own bussiness.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use it that way. Since "head first" is a metaphor suggesting physical movement, the verb in your sentence could be "dove", staying within the metaphor.
"He dove headfirst into his new business."